# How can I whitelist Multiverse worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible to whitelist Multiverse worlds, so only certain players can, for example, go to a survival world?

Even if they try to `/tp` to a player in a world they're not allowed in, it won't allow them.

Comment: I assume that you want a mod recommendation? Those are off-topic here. Also, what is "Multiverse"? If you use anything non-standard, you should at least give a short explanation or a link.

Comment: @FabianRöling Are they, actually? I know it's asking for a software recommendation, but the answer [this question on meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions) (which is old, but still seems relevant) seems to suggest otherwise. Especially since this question here only offers it is a possible solution to a problem that might be able to get solved differently. 'Multiverse' seems to be 'world management software' for servers, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, it makes use of Permissions: for example [PermissionsEx](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/)

> If a player has multiverse.access.WORLDNAME, then they can enter that world.

**NOTE: Ensure you have enforceaccess enabled in your Multiverse "config.yml". If enforceaccess is set to false anyone can go to any world and all world-access permissions are ignored.**

### Ingame

For each world:

> perm player setperm [player_name] multiverse.access.[world_name]

For all worlds:

> perm player setperm [player_name] multiverse.access.*

Where **[player_name]** is the name of the player
and **[world_name]** is the name of the world

### Automation

For automation you have to edit the "permission.yml", for example:

```
groups:
    default:
        permissions:
            - multiverse.access.[overworld_name]
    admin:
        permissions:
            - multiverse.access.*
        inheritance:
        - default
users:    
    [player_name]:                
        groups:
        - admin
```

(Where [overworld_name] is the name of the overworld)

This automatically enables the overworld access for everyone, while admins have access to all the worlds.
**You should to get to know how "Permissions" works, before trying large scale permission edit, since this can break the game (unable to do certain actions)**

### Other commands / permissions

See [**Command reference**](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/Command-Reference) for more permissions / commands.

### Source

see [**Github**](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/permissions#multiverse-world-permissions) for more explanation (which is the source)

Comment: Does it work with group manager

Comment: @kingbluesapphire as seeing from [Group Manager](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager), yes it does work with group manager as well.